# How to implement k-fold cross validation with multi-class SVM

Tags: matlab, svm, cross-validation

I'm working on age prediction topic and I could implement multi-class SVM with 11 classes by train each one with positives vs all rest as shown [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39352-multi-class-svm) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33170-multi-class-support-vector-machine). 
But the problem is in `for` loops, as shown below, training data need to 11 loops:

```
for k = 1:numClasses
    %Vectorized statement that binarizes Group
    %where 1 is the current class and 0 is all other classes
    G_x_All = (train_label == u(k));
    G_x_All = double (G_x_All);
    SVMStruct{k} = svmtrain(Data_Set, G_x_All);
end
```

Then, data classification need also to 11 loops for each image:

```
for j = 1:total_images
  for k = 1:numClasses
      if(svmclassify(SVMStruct{k}, Test_Img(j,:)));
          break;
      end
  end
  Age (j) = u(k); % Put the number of correct class in Age vector
end
```

My noob question is, How can I make a [k-fold cross validation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/crossvalind.html) after all these loops?

EDIT ::>

Here is the last update of the code depending on Mr. zelanix suggestions, but I got bad results. Could you help me to improve it's performance?

```
u = unique(train_label);
numClasses = length (u);
N = size (Data_Set,1)
A = 10;
indices = crossvalind('Kfold', N, A);
cp = classperf (train_label);

for i = 1:A
    Test = (indices == i); 
    Train = ~Test;         
    SVMStruct = cell(numClasses, 1); % Clear data structure.

    % Build models
  for k = 1:numClasses
    %Vectorized statement that binarizes Group
    %where 1 is the current class and 0 is all other classes
    G_x_All = (train_label == u(k));
    G_x_All = double (G_x_All);
    SVMStruct{k} = svmtrain(Data_Set (Train,:), G_x_All(Train,:));
  end

  Age = NaN(size(Data_Set, 1), 1);

  % Classify test cases
  for k = 1:numClasses
      if(svmclassify(SVMStruct{k}, Data_Set(Test,:)));
          break;
      end
  end
   Age = u(k);
   if Age == 1
       disp ('Under 10 years old');
   elseif Age == 10
       disp ('Between 10 and 20 years old');
   elseif Age == 20
       disp ('Between 20 and 30 years old');
   elseif Age == 30
       disp ('Between 30 and 40 years old');
   elseif Age == 40
       disp ('Between 40 and 50 years old');
   elseif Age == 50
       disp ('Between 50 and 60 years old');
   elseif Age == 60
       disp ('Upper 60 years old');
   else
       disp ('Unknown');
   end

classperf(cp, Age, Test);
    disp (i)
end
cp.CorrectRate
```

Note that I decreased the number of labels to 7 instead of 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general structure that you need is as follows (assuming that your data is in variable `your_data` with size `N` x `M` where `N` is the number of samples and `M` is the number of features and your class labels are in variable `your_classes` of size `M` x 1):

```
K = 10; % The number of folds
N = size(your_data, 1); % The number of data samples to train / test
idx = crossvalind('Kfold', N, K)

% your_classes should contain the class between 1 and numClasses.
cp = classperf(your_classes);

for i = 1:K
    Data_Set = your_data(idx ~= i, :); % The data to train on, 90% of the total.
    train_label = your_classes(idx ~= i, :); % The class labels of your training data.
    Test_Img = your_data(idx == i, :); % The data to test on, 10% of the total.
    test_label = your_classes(idx == i, :); % The class labels of your test data.

    SVMStruct = cell(numClasses, 1); % Clear data structure.

    % Your training routine, copied verbatim
    for k = 1:numClasses
        %Vectorized statement that binarizes Group
        %where 1 is the current class and 0 is all other classes
        G_x_All = (train_label == u(k));
        G_x_All = double (G_x_All);
        SVMStruct{k} = svmtrain(Data_Set, G_x_All);
    end

    Age = NaN(size(Test_Img, 1), 1);

    % Your test routine, copied (almost) verbatim
    for j = 1:size(Test_Img, 1)
      for k = 1:numClasses
          if(svmclassify(SVMStruct{k}, Test_Img(j,:)));
              break;
          end
      end
      Age(j) = u(k); % Put the number of correct class in Age vector
    end

    cp = classperf(cp, Age, idx == i);
end

cp.CorrectRate
```

This is untested, and I am not sure how your classification actually works. You seem to break on the first classification that matches, which is likely not the correct one, or indeed the most likely one. You also need some way to record this and match it against the true class label, in `test_label`. I suggest that you look into the [`classperf`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/classperf.html) function, but this is a separate question.

Note also that matlab has built in multiclass SVM classification in the [`fitcecoc`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcecoc.html) function which may be more suitable for your needs.

**EDIT** The problem with your updated code (as I mentioned above) is with your classification method. You loop through and test whether the sample belongs to each class and break on the first one matched. This is unlikely to be the *most likely* classification so I'm not surprised that you're getting poor results.

Your sample may be matched by the first model, but only by a small margin, but it doesn't get to the model that matches it well. It would be very unlikely to go past the first few classifications, and what would you do if it gets to the end and isn't matched by any classifier?

Multiclass classification using SVM is usually achieved by selecting the class where the sample is classified with highest likelihood (of all the classes where it tests positive, choose the one furthest from the decision boundary - `fitcecoc` does this internally). But this isn't possible manually using `svmclassify` because it doesn't give you access to these details.

`fitcecoc` still doesn't give you access to all the values that you might need though so if you really want to do this manually then I suggest that you look into [libsvm](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/), otherwise use `fitcecoc`.

As mentioned in the comments, `svmtrain` and `svmclassify` are now deprecated anyway - libsvm also provides a much larger possibility for tuning and performance not possible using the built-in MATLAB implementation.

As an aside, multiclass logistic regression is much simpler to understand and can achieve very good results too.

Comment: Thank you very much @zelanix for your help. I have edited the code to show next step after `break`. By the way, after implementing your code I have some questions: where I should put `train_label` and `test_label`? It looks unusable! Also, due using `K-fold`, I guess there is no need to `Test_Img` any more because it take the test image randomly from `Data_Set`, am I right?

Comment: I have updated the answer slightly to include recording of performance using `classperf`. I think that `classperf` requires the class labels to be `1:numClasses` though, and not transformed using `u(k)`. `train_label` is required and used in your training routine, but you are right that `test_label` is not used when implemented like this, but may be required for other implementation choices.

Comment: I have updated the code Mr. zelanix, could you check it? @zelanix

Comment: To be more precise: `svmtrain` and `svmclassify` will be deprecated in the future, the new package consists of `templateSVM`, `fitcecoc`, and `predict`.

Comment: @AbuQusay, I have updated my answer based on your updated code.

Comment: @Adriaan, yes, that's right - although I would always recommend to use libsvm over the MATLAB implementations for tuning and performance reasons. I have updated my answer to reflect.

Comment: Dear @zelanix, thank you very much for the code and explanation. I really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Thank you Mr. @Adriaan for your advice.